# I want to know the proof of this: if boolean algebra B is c.c.c., then stone space St(B) is c.c.c. Where can I see it?

Tags: logic, set-theory

I want to know the proof of this:
if boolean algebra $B$ is c.c.c., then stone space St($B$) is c.c.c.

Where can I see it?

===(memo)======
(definition)
B is c.c.c. $:\Leftrightarrow \forall S \subseteq B \backslash \{ 0 \} \;[ \forall x, y \in C \;[ 0 \lt x \cdot y \Rightarrow x = y] \Rightarrow |S| \leq \omega ]$
topological space X is c.c.c. $:\Leftrightarrow \forall {\cal S} \subseteq {\cal O}_X \backslash \{ \emptyset \} \;[ \forall U, V \in C \;[ \emptyset \not= U \cap V \Rightarrow U = V ] \Rightarrow |{\cal S}| \leq \omega ]$

St(B) $:\equiv \{ F \subseteq B : F \text{ is ultrafilter} \}$
$N : B \rightarrow (\text{Power set of St}(B)), x \mapsto \{ F \in \text{St}(B) : x \in F \}$
${\cal O}_{\text{St}(B)} :\equiv (\text{System of open sets generated by } \{ N(x) : x \in B \})$

(proof?)
let ${\frak F} \subseteq {\cal O}_{\text{St}(B)} \backslash \{ \emptyset \}$, and assume $\forall {\cal F}, {\cal G} \in {\frak F} \;\left[ {\cal F} \cap {\cal G} \not= \emptyset \Rightarrow {\cal F} = {\cal G} \right]$.

I don't know what I should do from here in order to conclude $|{\frak F}| \leq \omega$.
Should I define $B^\prime :\equiv \{ x \in B \backslash \{ 0 \} : N(x) \in {\frak F} \}$ ? or $B^\prime :\equiv \{ x \in B \backslash \{ 0 \} : \exists {\cal F} \in {\frak F} \;[\; N(x) \subseteq {\cal F} \;] \}$ ?

Comment: I would guess the proof is left as an exercise in most places. I recommend focusing on understanding the definitions well enough that the proof becomes trivial, rather than trying to find it written down somewhere.

Comment: For instance, what are the basic open sets in the Stone space and what does it mean if two of them are disjoint?

Comment: What is the Stone space of a Boolean algebra $B$? It's the totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space $X$ whose Boolean algebra of clopen sets is isomorphic to $B$, right? So you want a proof of the fact that, if $X$ is a totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space, and if the Boolean algebra of clopen subsets of $X$ satisfies the c.c.c., then the space $X$ satisfies the c.c.c. How do you define the c.c.c. for a topological space, and for a Boolean algebra?

Comment: pls teach me the proof.